# Python/Tkinter: Using the new ttk.Notebook widget (custom font, trapping tab focus/mouseover)

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using the new ttk.Notebook widget available in Python 2.7 and Python 3.1.

I'm struggling with the following tasks:

1. How to change the font associated with notebook tab captions. I want to use a named font object whose size a user controls. (Could a ttk.Style help me here?)
2. How can I bind to tab specific keyboard focus (<FocusIn>), mouseover events (<Enter>), and rightclicks (<Button-3>). I have a total fail trying to bind to tab specific keyboard focus and mouseover events. I can bind to a <Button-3> rightclick, but I can't figure out how to determine the tab a user clicked on. Using .identify( event.x, event.y ) returns the string 'label' vs. a widget reference.
3. Is there a way to give tabs an id (the documentation hints at this via tab_id) so we can reference tabs independent of their physical position in an array of tabs?

Thank you,
Malcolm

Comment: `notebook` tag removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score -1):

We're actually answering these questions in the Tkinter [mailing list](http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tkinter-discuss); in fact, I have mixed feelings about saying anything in Stackoverflow apart from, "See the mailing list".  It's surely fair to note, though, that [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2010-December/002626.html) answers the question about fonts, and [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2010-December/002623.html) heads a thread on tab events.

Comment: The TKinter mailing list is great and I highly recommend it to developers with Tkinter questions. However not all Tkinter developers subscribe to the Tkinter mailing list. I've found Stackoverflow an excellent *additional* source of support for Tkinter questions. BTW: Thanks for your help on the Tkinter mailing list.